# How do I pre-process few of my independent and the dependent variables while building an ML model in Flask?

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, preprocessor, non-linear-regression

It is a regression problem at hand to predict the Customer Lifetime value given the demographic data.
I have a total of 14 X variables which are a mix of categorical & numerical data.

```
X = ['Coverage', 'Education', 'EmploymentStatus', 'Income',
       'Marital Status', 'Months Since Last Claim',
       'Months Since Policy Inception', 'Number of Open Complaints',
       'Number of Policies', 'Renew Offer Type', 'Vehicle Class',
       'Vehicle Size', 'Monthly Premium Auto_boxcox',
       'Total Claim Amount_boxcox']

y = ['Customer Lifetime Value_boxcox']
```

The idea is to build a form where one can enter the X variables in the form and the Flask model will predict the Customer Lifetime Value.
Currently as you can see the data for Monthly Premium Auto & Total Claim amount was highly right skewed and hence the data was transformed using boxcox. 
**However how do I transform the user's input data?**

Also the Customer Lifetime Value is also transformed in boxcox, the results need to be untransformed to its original value in dollars. 
Im using spyder and flask to build this inspired by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbCWoMf80PY

Below are all my code files for your reference:
Data, app.py, model.py, index.html:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XHwX-AlDlzo_crhG5EIA8LEfVhtGpSmZ

Any help to make this front end better would he really great.
Thank you in advance!

*PS: I have read about pre-processing using request.py or Pipeline while building model, Im not sure how boxcox will fall in place and how to un-transform my Customer Lifetime Value.
Also Im absolutely new to this, request you to simplify your answers as much as possible.*

Answer (score 0):

I have used pipeline for this purpose and it worked well.
I created classes to perform the desired transformation for both numerical and categorical data and combined them using Feature Union.